# Downloading/unzipping/inserting with Oracle/PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to insert several different .csv Files, zipped as .gz, from an URL into the corresponding tables. These files also get added on a daily basis. My idea was to download them all into a directory (oracle/stuff for example), unzip them and then do the insert on .csv (automated on a specific time)

For example

```
`somerandomsite\stuff\budget-071220.csv.gz  
somerandomsite\stuff\budget-081220.csv.gz        
somerandomsite\stuff\sold-071220.csv.gz         
somerandomsite\stuff\sold-081220.csv.gz        
somerandomsite\stuff\buy-071220.csv.gz  
somerandomsite\stuff\buy-081220.csv.gz`
```

I don't know how to download them while only using PL/SQL? After that, my best guess is to just unzip everything in said directory but I'm also not sure what would be the easiest way to get all the .csv into the corresponding tables? Loading them via Regex in external Tables + Insert Into?

Comment: Consider an ETL tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have APEX installed in your database and the files are available through a REST API, you can call the REST API and insert the files directly into the database with a single insert statement similar to the one below. `apex_web_service.make_rest_request_b` makes the REST request for the file, `UTL_COMPRESS.lz_uncompress` unzips the gz file, and finally `apex_data_parser.parse` can be used to read the CSV file as if it was a table which you can select from to insert into your destination table.

```sql
INSERT INTO your_table (column1, column2)
    SELECT col001, col002
      FROM TABLE (
               apex_data_parser.parse (
                   p_content     =>
                       UTL_COMPRESS.lz_uncompress (
                           apex_web_service.make_rest_request_b (
                               p_url           => 'http://yourserver.com/rest/api/budget-071220.csv.gz',
                               p_http_method   => 'GET')),
                   p_file_type   => 2, --2 is for CSV
                   p_skip_rows   => 0));
```

Comment: This seem like a great solution, thank you. I'll try it at earliest opportunity.
apex_web_service.make_request_b should work too, if no REST is available?

Comment: If a REST API is not available to retrieve the files, I would have the files copied to a folder accessible by Oracle, then load the file into a BLOB using `DBMS_LOB.loadblobfromfile`. You can then use the blob that was loaded in place of the  `apex_web_service.make_rest_request_b` call in the INSERT statement

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is by combination of shell script and pl/sql(block or stored procedure).This approach is good if the file is relatively smaller.

1. Shell script can be scheduled to run at a time that can read a folder and unzip the files and then trigger the pl/sql procedure.
2. pl/sql procedure to read the files using utl_file and process records line by line. Add exceptions to log bad records to a seperate folder/file using utl_file that can be investigate post the load.

If the file is huge in say few Gigs,SQL*LOADER is an option as that is much faster than stored procedures.

Comment: I was already thinking along the same lines as I read the OP question. One tweak - I'd use sqlldr (or external table) regardless.  I'd not complicate the issue by trying to decide if the file is "big enough" to "justify" the use of sqlldr.

Comment: Unfortunately Shell script ist not an option in my case, but thank you for your suggestion.